# switch functions in c

Tags: c, function, struct, switch-statement

Trying to create a menu driven employee data program. I don't know how to create a functioning menu and also having trouble getting the menu options to work such as editing previously entered employee info. I would appreciate any help I can get on this. The errors that are currently arising are

1. edit employees function: redefinition; different basic types.
2. In `main`—when calling the menu function I am using `menu(&payroll)`, the error message is, cannot convert from `input*` to `input`.
3. Also in main—the function `employeeInfo(&payroll)` is giving an error message, cannot convert from `input*` to `input`.

I'm sure there are many other mistakes I am making if you see any please guide me in the right direction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//This is a macro intended for use with the emplyName array.
#define SIZE 20 

//This struct has all the varibles that I will be using in my functions
typedef struct
{
    char emplyName[5][SIZE];
    float emplyHours[5];
    float emplyRate[5];
    float emplyGross[5];
    float emplyBase[5];
    float emplyOvrt[5];
    float emplyTax[5];
    float emplyNet[5];
    float emplyTotal[5];
}input;

void menu(void);
void employeeInfo(input* emply);
void editEmployees(input* emply);
void print(input* emply);

int main(void)
{
    input payroll={"",0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
    int choice;
    menu(&payroll);
    scanf_s("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice){
    case '1': 
        employeeInfo(&payroll);
        break;
    case '2':
        editEmployees(&payroll);
        break;
    case '3':
        break;
    case '4':
        print(&payroll);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid entry\n");
    }
    system("pause");
}

void employeeInfo(input *emply)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        printf("Enter employee name -1 to end.\n");
        scanf_s("%s", &emply->emplyName[i]);
        if (strcmp(emply->emplyName[i], "-1") == 0){
            break;
        }

        printf("Enter employee hours.\n");
        scanf_s("%f", &emply->emplyHours[i]);
        printf("Enter Hourly rate.\n");
        scanf_s("%f", &emply->emplyRate[i]);
    }
}
void calculations(input *emply)/*Write a method that calculates the gross, base and overtime pay, pass by reference.*/
{
    int i;
    i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if (emply->emplyHours[i] > 40) {
            emply->emplyOvrt[i] = (emply->emplyHours[i] - 40) * (emply->emplyRate[i] * 1.5);
        }
        emply->emplyGross[i] = (((emply->emplyHours[i])*(emply->emplyRate[i])) + emply->emplyOvrt[i]);
        emply->emplyBase[i] = (emply->emplyGross[i]) - (emply->emplyOvrt[i]);
        emply->emplyTax[i] = ((emply->emplyGross[i])*.2);
        emply->emplyNet[i] = (emply->emplyGross[i]) - (emply->emplyTax[i]);
        emply->emplyTotal[0] += emply->emplyGross[i];
    }


}


void print(input *emply)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(emply->emplyName[i], "-1") == 0){
            break;
        }
        printf("Employee Name:%s\n", emply->emplyName[i]);
        printf("Hours Worked:%.2f\n ", emply->emplyHours[i]);
        printf("Hourly Rate:%.2f\n", emply->emplyRate[i]);
        printf("Gross Pay:%.2f\n", emply->emplyGross[i]);
        printf("Base Pay:%.2f\n", emply->emplyBase[i]);
        printf("Overtime Pay:%.2f\n", emply->emplyOvrt[i]);
        printf("Taxes Paid:%.2f\n", emply->emplyTax[i]);
        printf("Net Pay:%.2f\n", emply->emplyNet[i]);
    }
    printf("Total paid to all employees : %.2f\n", emply->emplyTotal[0]);
}
void editEmployees(input *emply){
    int j;
    int index = 1;
    int i;
    printf("Choose an employee.");
    for (j = 1; j < 5; j++); {
        printf("%d.%s", index, emply->emplyName[j]);
    }
    scanf_s("%d", &i);
    employeeInfo(emply);

}
void menu(void){
    printf("Main Menu\n");
    printf("1. Add Employee\n");
    printf("2. Edit Employee\n");
    printf("3. Print Employee\n");
    printf("4. Print All EMployees\n");
    printf("0. exit\n");

}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea what the error messages mean?

Comment: @ OP, atleast, try to know. Search, research.

Comment: Your data structure is wrong. You should define a struct that holds data for ONE employee, then use an array of such structs.

Comment: @n.m., so your saying should create 5 different structs for five different employees ??

Comment: No, you should create an *array*, not "5 differet structs".

Answer (score 2):

To start with

> *1. edit employees function: redefinition; different basic types.*

You need to forward declare the function prototype.

> *2. `menu(&payroll)` cannot convert from 'input*' to 'input'.*

Your function declaration and definition  does not match.

- in declaration, you have `void menu(input payroll);`
- in definition, you have `void menu(void){ //`
- you call with `menu(&payroll);`

all the above three are different. Stick to any one.

> *3. employeeInfo(&payroll)  cannot convert from 'input*' to 'input'.*

Again, mismatch between function declaration and definition. Change your function declaration

```
void employeeInfo(input payroll);
```

to

```
void employeeInfo(input* payroll);
```

Comment: I made the adjustment that you suggested but now it is saying that I'm using uninitialized local variables "i" in the editEmployee function and 'choice' in main

Comment: @lvlayhelvl ya, compiler is right. don't you think `scanf_s("%d", i, 1);` is wrong? Did you check the manual page for that?

Comment: I left the & out.... so I fixed that and nothing happens when I make the selection, how can I fix my switch?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all we have to solve some issues. The most importat is to make it compile. So I've added a couply of comments to the code where you have to make some adjustments. When u've done it, u will be able to compile and we will improve the code further. **See all comments that starts with // BAD: ...**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//! Add comment here
#define SIZE 20

//! Add some description aswell
typedef struct
{
    ...
    ...
}input;

//! Add prototypes to all functions! Except main
void menu(input payroll);           // BAD: Prototype does not match     declaration. Copy from the declaration.
void employeeInfo(input payroll);   // BAD: Prototype does not match. You     forgot to set this as a pointer as well.

int main(void)
{
    ...
    ..

    menu(&payroll); // BAD: Remove input. Function is a void

    scanf_s("%d", choice);  // BAD: Point to the address : &choice

    switch (choice){
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

}

void employeeInfo(input *emply)
{
    ...

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        ...
        scanf_s("%s", &emply->emplyName[i], SIZE);  // BAD: No need to pass the size of scanf. Remove SIZE

        ...
        ...
    }
}
void calculations(input *emply)/*Write a method that calculates the gross,     base and overtime pay, pass by reference.*/
{
    ...
    ...

}


void print(input *emply)
{
    ...
    ...
}

void editEmployees(input *emply){
    ....
    scanf_s("%d", i, 1);    // BAD: Only one argument is needed. You forgot to point to address. &i, remove 1
    employeeInfo(*emply->emplyName[i-1]);   // BAD: function expects the struct ! Not a member of the struct. Change to emply

}
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Made all the necessary adjustment and yes it does compile. I will edit my code above to reflect the changes.